# Dissolve in python script not working correctly

Tags: arcpy, arcgis-10.2, dissolve

I have a python script that merges 12 shapefiles into 1 shapefile with about 75k total records.  I want to dissolve the latter shapefile on a particular field, and SUM another field, so my final shapefile has 12 records in it based on the dissolve field.

I can do this in ArcMap 10.2 with no problem, but when I do it from my python script outside of ArcMap, my final shapefile, instead of having 12 dissolved records, has about 20 (some are repeats).  The field I dissolve on is a text field with distance such as 1000mile.shp, 2000mile.shp, etc...

Anyone know a workaround to make this work out of my python script?

```
arcpy.Dissolve_management(fc, "dissolvetracts.shp", "dist_band", [["LGH001","SUM"], ["Shape_area","SUM"]], "MULTI_PART", "DISSOLVE_LINES")
```

Comment: If you've gotten it to work manually through the UI, then I would suggest to create a model via ModelBuilder (MB), set up the tool in there, run it, (if it works) then export out the python script from MB to see the proper statement syntax.

Comment: That is a great idea.  I'll try that later today.

Comment: Alternatively to what artwork21 suggests, you can open the Results window in ArcMap and right-click the tool result and choose copy as Python snippet. Look at syntax there.

Comment: Still no luck.  The dissolve starts at line 136 of my code, and from what I've read, the dissolve gets a little crazy after a lot of memory is used...thanks for the thoughts!  I will just dissolve each shapefile individually, and then merge those together.

Comment: Dissolve is just crazy.  Apparently it tiles large datasets, regardless of parameters, so it'll separate the data in pieces, which is the opposite of what I want to do.  I'm now running my python script out of ArcMap, and it works, and seems to be more stable.

Comment: I am using python script outside the arcmap with a huge shapefile to dissolve and it creates tiles as you said. Also, when I do it inside ArcMap, it works perfectly. Any thoughts??